# given a set of points, $T$, on the surface of $\mathbb{S}^n$, does a $t \in T$ lie in every possible hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$?

Tags: spherical-geometry

Consider the $n$-dimensional hypersphere, $\mathbb{S}^n$.  Given a set of points, $T$, on the surface of $\mathbb{S}^n$, we wish to determine whether at least one $t \in T$ lies in (including on the boundary of) any possible hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$.

- what are the most elegant sufficiency conditions?
- what are the most efficient sufficiency conditions?

In the special case in which $t, t' \in T$ are antipodal, then we are done.

As this is not a Hamiltonian path problem (so, not as obviously threatened by greedy algorithms?), a 'nearest antipodes' approach seems a good start:

1. start with the most isolated $t \in T$;
2. if its antipode $t'$ is in $T$, stop;
3. otherwise, determine the closest $t'' \in T$ to $t' \ldots$

The [$n = 2$ case](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000201909/000000000020190a#problem) was presented in the 2017 World Finals of Code Jam, as a problem in 'omnicircumnavigation'.

Comment: Given *any* set of points in $\mathbb{S}^n$?

Comment: Yes: $T$ can be any set of points on the surface of $\mathbb{S}^n$.  Given some $T$, we want to know whether at least one $t \in T$ lies in any possible hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$.  If my original question can be improved, please let me know: I may be missing nuances.

Comment: But if your set of points $T$ are all contained in one hemisphere (without boundary), then the opposite hemisphere (with boundary) contains none of them. Maybe I'm missing something. Think of $S^2$ as the earth. If you take a set of points strictly in the northern hemisphere, none of these points are either in the southern hemisphere or on the equator, so there is a hemisphere containing none of them

Comment: Yes, correct: in your example, we can easily determine that $T$ fails the test.  We want a simple condition that generalises from "south of the equator" to "on one side of any possible great circle".